# Using both Rsymphony and slam to solve linear programme

Tags: r, linear-programming, glpk

I am trying to solve a LP problem using Rsymphony. There is nothing special about my code, apart - maybe - from the fact that I am using slam to create a sparse constraint matrix (`model_list$constr` below). The code looks like this (the entire problem is to big to post):

```
Rsymphony_solve_LP(arcs$cost, 
                   model_list$constr, 
                   model_list$constr_dir, 
                   model_list$rhs$sd, 
                   max = FALSE)
```

The error I get is:

```
Error in Rsymphony_solve_LP(arcs$cost, model_list$constr, model_list$constr_dir,  : 
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

I am pretty sure that the model isn't wrong. it works with Rglpk (but I would like to use Rsymphony, because it seems to be faster, cf. http://strimas.com/prioritization/ilp-performance/):

```
Rglpk_solve_LP(arcs$cost,
               model_list$constr,
               model_list$constr_dir,
               model_list$rhs$sd,
               max = FALSE)
```

Comment: I am not sure the R wrapper `Rsymphony_solve_LP` accepts a sparse matrix (although Symphony itself does). What happens if you pass the data as a normal (dense) matrix?

Comment: If I use `as.matrix(model_list$constr)`, I get a memory error.

Comment: I guess you are running out of memory. I think one can write an R wrapper for Symphony that accepts a sparse matrix. Just use the current wrapper as an example.